# Integrate over a curve (complex)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Given

$${\Gamma} = [{z(t) = t\sqrt{\frac2\pi\}}e^{it^2}}]$$ for   $$0< t < \sqrt{\pi/2}$$

evaluate

$$\int_{\Gamma} ze^{z^2}dz$$

The usual process involves parametrization and then substituting z(t) into f(z) which in this case is the stuff under the integral and then multiplying by z'(t). Generally a simple enough process. Here however I end up with a ridiculously messy integral that I have no idea what to do with. Surely there's something I'm missing or some way to simplify ${\Gamma}$. What do?

Comment: What do those square parentheses in gamma's definition mean?

Comment: Nothing. Just a way to group z(t) together. Ironically I was trying to make it look simpler.

Comment: Then use the international sign for sets, @PatrickJayne: curly parentheses {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you may simply evaluate the integral at the endpoints of $\Gamma$ because

$$\int dz \, z \, e^{z^2} = \frac12 e^{z^2} + C$$

The endpoints are at $z=0$ and $z=e^{i \pi/2} = i$.

Comment: Ah, so I need not worry about the curve if the endpoints are the same?

Comment: That's right - the integrand is analytic and thus the integral is path-independent.